# Use generics without collections

Tags: java

Let's say I have the folowing:

```
List<Apple> myList = new ArrayList<Apple>();
```

And if I want to call `myList.add(myApple)`, Java expects from `myApple` to have type of `Apple`, not any others (except subclasses of course). But what if I want to have an object (`Blender`) and have different method signatures according to type declared inside `<>` and *without* method overloadings; like so:

```
Blender<Apple> Tool = new Blender<Apple>();
Tool.blendIt(new Apple()); //expects to have only apples in here

Blender<Banana> OtherTool = new Blender<Banana>();
OtherTool.blendIt(new Banana()); //only Banana's are permitted
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can check if its an instance of `Banana` or `Apple` with the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Yes I can, but it will get bad as soon as I put `Strawberry` inside the `Blender` :) So flexible solution is required

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are looking for [**Generic Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

```
class Blender<T>{
T t;
public void blendIt(T arg){
//stuff
}
}

class Test {
   public void method() {
     Blender<Apple> blendedApple = new Blender<Apple>();
     blendedApple.blendIt(new Apple()); 
     Blender<Bannana> blendedBannana = new Blender<Bannana>();     
     blendedBannana.blendIt(new Bannana());
   }
 }
```

Comment: @TomatoMato you are welcome. :) also remember that you cannot use wildcard's in the declaration of generic class. i.e., class Blender<?>  is a compiler error:) btw, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is:

```
public class Blender<T> {
   public void blendIt(T arg) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java generics are NOT just for `Collections` only. It is a general concept and applies to classes, methods, etc. You can create a generic class.